# Lambda capture with std::move and this

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda, stdmove

I'm actually working to delete most of my copy constructor/assignation, and I faced an issue when comming to lambda use:

###### ThreadPool:

```cpp
using Task = std::function<void()>;

template<size_t S>
void ThreadPool<S>::enqueue(Task _task)
{
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

        m_queue.push(_task);
    }
    m_cond.notify_one();
}
```

###### My actual issue:

```cpp
class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass();            // some implementation
        ~MyClass();           // some implementation

        void process(Data &_data)
        {
            if (_data.data == 1)
                m_tp.enqueue([this, data = std::move(_data)] () {
                    func1(data);
                });
            else if (_data.data == 2)
                m_tp.enqueue([this, data = std::move(_data)] () {
                    func2(data);
                });
            else
                m_tp.enqueue([this, data = std::move(_data)] () {
                    func3(data);
                });
        }

        void MyClass::func1(const Data &_data)
        {
            // use of data
        }

        // func2 and func3 have the same signature

    private:
        ThreadPool<4> m_tp{};
};
```

`Data` class only declare move constructor/assignation, but when doing so, I got this error:

```
> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h: In instantiation of ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor&&) [with _Functor = MyClass::process(Data&)::<lambda()>; _Constraints = void; _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {}]’:
> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:439:69: error: static assertion failed: std::function target must be copy-constructible
>  439 |           static_assert(is_copy_constructible<__decay_t<_Functor>>::value,
> /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:439:69: note: ‘std::integral_constant<bool, false>::value’ evaluates to false
> ...
```

But I can't figure out, how to fix this compilation error and keep the `std::move(_data)` in lambda capture. I tried using `mutable` but it just give me the same error if I use it on all of the lambda and some similar error if I just use it on one.

Comment: I'm having to do a lot of patching to turn this into a workable example. By the time I'm done I will probably have accidentally fixed the problem you're asking about or slipped in a different one. It's in your best interests to provide a [mre].

Comment: `Data` must be copy-constructible in order for the lambda itself to be copy-constructible which is a requirement to use it as part of `std::function` (for any callable). In C++23 there is `std::move_only_function` to replace `std::function` if you want to store potentially non-copyable callables. But instead of using `std::function` you can simply make `Task` a template parameter and it will work with any callable (although not to store it in a class member without manual type erasure).

Comment: [There we go](https://godbolt.org/z/c44dbM76P). Oversimplified `Data` the first time around. @user17732522 the most recent edit tells us why. They only implemented moves.

Comment: @user17732522 `Data` isn't copyable because I don't wan't to have it copy to the lambda, I could do so, but my goal is to get ride of most copy constructor/assignation.

Comment: `std::function` simply doesn't support this use case. It _always_ must store a copyable callable (meaning the lambda captures must be copyable as well). That's a design decision.

Comment: Ok, so what the point to have an `std::move` in the capture if it's not to be able to just use the move assignation? And why does the design choice is to have copy-constructable only in lambda capture?

Comment: @DipStax The `std::move` in the capture moves the `Data` object into the lambda. That works just fine. The problem is that the lambda then stores a `Data` object (however it was constructed), so the lambda can't be copied, but `std::function` doesn't work with non-copyable callables. The problem lies purely in `std::function`. It has nothing to do with the lambda syntax.

Comment: Please make sure to remove all code irrelevant to reproducing your problem.  This question has way too much extraneous code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda is always going to be non-copyable because its closure type must have a `Data` member (which is intentionally non-copyable).

However, `std::function` by design requires all callable that it stores to be copyable so that the `std::function` object itself can also be copied with value semantics (i.e. the stored callable is actually copied, two `std::function` instances don't reference the same callable object).

So you can't store such a lambda in a `std::function`.

In C++23 there is `std::move_only_function` which *can't* be copied and so doesn't require the stored callable to be copyable either. It also improves on some other issues with `std::function`'s design. In C++26 there will also `std::copyable_function` which is again copyable by virtue of requiring stored callables to be copyable while also making `std::move_only_function`'s other design improvements over `std::function`.

If you can't use `std::move_only_function`, then you'll have to implement analogues move-only type erasure manually in order to store the lambda as a class member. Although, for just the call to `enqueue`, it would be sufficient to replace `Task` with an unconstrained template parameter to accept the lambda directly.